# Most appropriate type for opaque extern static in Rust?

Tags: rust, types, static, undefined-behavior, ffi

I want to obtain a raw pointer to an FFI-defined static, *whose concrete type is opaque to Rust*.

This is what I currently have:

```rust
use std::{ffi::c_void, ptr::addr_of};

fn ptr_to_foo() -> *const c_void {
    extern "C" {
        static FOO: /* what type here? */;
    }

    unsafe { addr_of!(FOO).cast() }
}
```

But with what type should `FOO` be declared?

Is it UB to declare it `c_void`, given that the bytes at the memory location may not be valid for that type—even though I only create a raw pointer to that location without ever constructing a reference (or worse, dereferencing the pointer/reading the memory)?

If so, is there anything more suitable/appropriate than `u8` or would that (or a newtype around it) be the recommended approach?

Comment: One cold almost think you didn't read the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/enum.c_void.html) which states "To model pointers to opaque types in FFI, until extern type is stabilized, it is recommended to use a newtype wrapper around an empty byte array"

Comment: To my reading, that is suggesting that instead of `*const c_void` one should prefer `*const SomeNewType` with `struct SomeNewType([u8; 0])` in order that such pointers are differentiated at the type level from other such opaque pointers.  It does not however mean that it's advisable or safe to declare an `extern static` as such a newtype any more than it is to declare it as a `c_void`.

Comment: That said, it occurs to me that since one can declare the static without an `unsafe` block, it *should* be safe no matter what type one chooses.  The potential unsafety only arises when obtaining its address, i.e. within the `unsafe` block above... and I believe that my use of the `addr_of!` macro here (rather than, say, casting a reference to a raw pointer) is indeed safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on nightly, use [extern types](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1861-extern-types.html). They are a nightly-only method to create a dynamically sized type that the compiler knows it can't dereference under any circumstance and are specifically designed for use in ffi.

```rust
#![feature(extern_types)]
extern "C"{
    type Foo;
    static FOO: Foo;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f64b2a1079a9ed60a3960bc767fec4d)

The other option is to use a zero-sized type with a private field and no public constructor:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct Foo{
    _inner: [u8;0]
}

extern "C"{
    static FOO: Foo;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a6ea2208f6d900d6c9ba7b17c5ab0a0a)

ZST reads and writes are always valid if the pointer you are using is non-null, well-aligned, and not pointing toward deallocated memory, so while you can still read from the static, doing so is well-defined. The only thing to be careful of is that casting the returned pointers into mutable references will result in undefined behavior if they are aliased, but that's an issue with statics, rather than the types.

Comment: In the second example, using `repr(C)` instead of `repr(transparent)` avoids the `improper_ctypes` warning.  And while I can see that these answers add more type-safety than `c_void`, I'm still trying to convince myself that such declarations are not UB (though the comment I made above re `unsafe` block not being required has somewhat convinced me that it shouldn't be the case).

Comment: @eggyal nice catch with the `repr(C)`. Declaring an `extern static` inappropriately can't cause UB all by itself, only linking errors at worst. Accessing an `extern static` can cause UB, but won't in either of the cases I mentioned because actually accessing the pointer is impossible. ZST reads and writes are nops, and reading or writing to an opaque type is forbidden by the compiler.